# Data Input JSON Format for Tensorflow Saved Model

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, tensorflow2.0, prediction, google-cloud-ai

I'm new to tensorflow and I've served the saved model to Google AI Platform models. However, I am having issues with the format of sample input data. Can you please guide how should I format the data input based on the requested format below? Thanks in advance.

To request an online prediction, it is required to input data instances as a JSON object as follow.

```
{
  "instances": [
    <value>|<simple/nested list>|<object>,
    ...
  ]
}
```

below is part of the outputs from $saved_model_cli --dir path /home/.. --all
In summary, I have 12 data inputs as string values. How should I put together in the above request format so the model can return prediction? Thanks!

```
Defined Functions:
  Function Name: '__call__'
    Option #1
      Callable with:
        Argument #1
          DType: list
          Value: [TensorSpec(shape=(None, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='a_xf'), TensorSpec(shape=(None, 2), dtype=tf.float32, name='b_xf'), TensorSpec(shape=(None, 8), dtype=tf.float32, name='c_xf'), TensorSpec(shape=(None, 12), dtype=tf.float32, name='d_xf'), TensorSpec(shape=(None, 4), dtype=tf.float32, name='e_xf'), TensorSpec(shape=(None, 16), dtype=tf.float32, name='f_xf'), TensorSpec(shape=(None, 26), dtype=tf.float32, name='g_xf'), TensorSpec(shape=(None, 4), dtype=tf.float32, name='h_xf'), TensorSpec(shape=(None, 2), dtype=tf.float32, name='i_xf'), TensorSpec(shape=(None, 11), dtype=tf.float32, name='j_xf'), TensorSpec(shape=(None, 6), dtype=tf.float32, name='k_xf'), TensorSpec(shape=(None, 2), dtype=tf.float32, name='l_xf')]
        Argument #2
          DType: bool
          Value: False
        Argument #3
          DType: NoneType
          Value: None
```